# Howto order and manage ordered items

Tags: drupal, evaluating-civicrm

I use Drupal 7.43 with CiviCRM 4.7.2. My task is to create a little form for ordering items. It is just one single item which can be ordered and the payment can be done later on via bank transfer.

I only need to track how many of these items get ordered (up to 10) in each transaction by a (most of the time) newly added contact. Both, the person who did order the item(s) and the web page owner should receive an email after sending the form.

I want to offer a sum in the email since there will be a delivery fee too.

So far I figured I should use a CiviCRM profile. It was easy to create a custom field for the amount of items. But I shouldn't attach this custom field to contacts since contacts should be able to make as many orders as they want and new orders shouldn't overwrite older orders. I don't understand how I can collect order details independent from contacts within CiviCRM. Of course all orders should have a unique ID.

In addition to that I don't get where I am supposed to do the actual calculation for the sum.

Do you know any guide I could follow? Fully fetched shop systems clearly would be much more than I need. I want to keep it as simple as possible.

Or should I work with Drupal contacts instead? I do use CiviCRM mainly for its comfortable mass mailing capabilities.

Comment: Have you looked at https://drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm

Comment: Thank you for the link. I didn't know this module and will check it out.